# Can I test performance of one section in my application with XCTest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, xctest

As I am little bit aware about `UNIT testing` with Xcode `XCTest` target I want to know that in my project, there is one section which contains many `animations` and many services and `database` process over there so how to measure performance of that screen in `XCTest` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are methods for measuring performance in `XCTestCase`: [measure](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xctestcase/1496290-measure) and [measureMetrics](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xctestcase/1496277-measuremetrics).

These methods execute the code inside the block ten times and report individual execution times, average time and deviation. They also set a base line for each tested device and report a test failure if the measured part of your code becomes significantly slower in the future.

The Xcode template for Unit Test Case files has one performance test method example at the bottom:

```
class CoreDataTestTests: XCTestCase {

    func testPerformanceExample() {
        self.measure {
            // Put the code you want to measure the time of here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So here I need to measure my animation + db data fetching speed so I need to put that code in this measure block or just call that function through XCTest Class ?

Comment: Keep the code where it is and call that function from within the measure block in the test method. The method under test needs to be public or internal (if it is internal: import its module with `@testable`). Run the test by clicking the little diamond shape in the breakpoint gutter, or run all tests using the Product->Test menu command. For animation performance you might also want to check Instruments, there are tools for animation performance profiling.

Comment: Thanks for your answer let me check the same.

Comment: @CodeChanger - just note that your animations run asynchrously, so you will need to use XCTestExpectation and waitForExpectation, otherwise your test will complete before the async code does.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to do with the results.

If you want to test the performance of your function for some kind of benchmarking to see if things get slower or faster after changes are made to that code, then check what `nils` suggested.

If you want to know what is taking processing time, then you are better off getting the exact measurements using `Instruments`. You can run Instruments from the `Product` menu, using `Profile` or `command+i`.

Choose `time profiler` and run the process (using the red circle button) on the device. Note that it helps to enable a few settings in order to see the data more clearly.

[image]

Use your app as a user would and observe the call tree in real time as it shows what functions are taking the most processor time.

From here you can see what might need optimisation etc.

Note: You might need to enable dSYM in your build settings in order to get the symbols rather than random memory offsets in the trace.

[image]

Instruments is a great tool for knowing what is going on in your app. You can check CPU core usage, thread usage and thread waiting etc.